# tomcat trim white spaces

Tags: tomcat, trim, removing-whitespace

I'm using tomcat 8 and have to following directive in the app's web.xml within the web-app construct but spaces are not being trimmed.  Any ideas what is wrong or how to debug it?

```
  <jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the native trim-directive-whitespaces directive doesn't seem to work but this lib does.  It also removes HTML comments.

http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/trimflt.htm